# Configuring samba to change ownership virtually

Tags: linux, samba, file-permissions, file-server

We have 2 ubuntu 8.04 LTS fileservers running samba version *3.0.28a-1ubuntu4.12*, they export samba shares for windows server 2003 machines. There is no windows AD domain, just plain user authentication. From `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        security = SHARE
        passdb backend = smbpasswd:/etc/samba/smbpasswd
        unix password sync = no
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        dns proxy = No
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        encrypt passwords = true
        invalid users = root
        hosts allow = 10.1.1.0/24

[md0]
        comment = md0
        path = /mnt/md0/smb/share1
        valid users = user1
        force user = root
        force group = root
        read only = no
        create mask = 0660
        directory mask = 0770
        browseable = Yes
```

`/mnt/md0/` is a raid system and file permissions are `root.root` for historical reasons.

On a windows server 2003 machine we access the share with a script:

```
net use t: \\fileserver0\md0 passwordforuser1 /user:user1
```

On the windows machine we now see `Unix user\root` as the owner:

[image]

This is logically correct.

But is there a chance to change samba configuration so we see `user1.user1` as owner on the windows side instead of `Unix user\root`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You could adjust the groupmappings in samba, to adjust the group that will be shown :

```
net groupmap add unixgroup=root ntgroup=user1
```

Second, You can map individual users by modifying samba.conf by adding

```
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
```

to the [global] section, and then making the file /etc/samba/smbusers containing :

```
root: user1
```

Comment: Thank you. It works for the group but the user that windows sees is still root.

Comment: I tried to change the last line to `root = user1`. Now there is an error on the winodws side when user1 tries to connect. Is there anything more I need to change? Maybe the `force`statement or something in the samba config needs more tweaking?

Comment: Do you have any relevant logs on your server about this error?

Comment: I had a look at the logs and could solve it. I had forgotten to update the password with smbpasswd. Thank you.